# Why does this SSE handler cause the client connection to be stuck in pending?

Tags: javascript, go, server-sent-events

In this example, https://github.com/kljensen/golang-html5-sse-example/blob/d4eba81ddea2b4191f039adb6929086ca6b39c0f/server.go#L130, you can block on a channel. But doing that in my `HandleExecute` results in the browser/client connection status to remain stuck in a pending state and nothing gets sent to the client.

If I remove the for loop and use a select statement with a default case writing back no data, then it works (`execute` writes and flushes data) except that the handler returns and the client re-connects every 5 seconds instead of maintaining the connection. When I do it that way, the client gets streamed data only on the reconnect intervals.

So users end up seeing a delay lasting anywhere less than 5 seconds depending on when `HandleExecuteRequest` gets hit. `HandleExecute` could be ready to write but the client may not have reconnected yet. I hope that makes sense.

How can I write these handlers to maintain a constant connection instead of reconnecting?

```
func (s *Server) HandleExecuteRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error parsing request: %v", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error parsing request: %v", err)
        return
    }

    decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
    var f Form
    err = decoder.Decode(&f, r.PostForm)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error decoding form: %v", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error decoding form: %v", err)
        return
    }

    s.clientMap[r.RemoteAddr] <- buildCommand(&f)
}

func (s *Server) HandleExecute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    s.addClient(r)

    for {
        cmd := <-s.clientMap[r.RemoteAddr]
        execute(w, cmd)
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
var source = new EventSource('<host>/execute');
source.onmessage = function(e) {
document.querySelector("code").innerHTML +="<span class='font-weight-bold' style='white-space: pre-wrap; padding-left: 200px;'>" + e.data + "</span>" + "<br>"
};
```

If I update `HandleExecute` to below, I get a continuous connection but then `HandleExecuteRequest` gets stuck in pending when that is hit. It could how I'm setting up the clients and handling the channels in this case.

```
func (s *Server) HandleExecute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    s.addClient(r)

    for {
        select {
        case cmd := <-s.clientMap[r.RemoteAddr]:
            execute(w, cmd)
        default:
            fmt.Fprint(w, ": no data\n\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it deliberately designed so that `HandleExecute` never returns?

Comment: @zerkms In this description, yes. When I remove the for loop and add a select with a default case that writes empty data to the http.ResponseWriter so that the handler returns, everything works more smoothly except that the client reconnects every 5 seconds instead of just maintaining the connection. I want to setup the server to maintain the connection instead of having the client reconnect every 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you realise that you leak goroutines with it though?

Comment: I don't realize, no.

Answer (score -1):

My issue had nothing to do with how the SSE handler was set up. My channel was not being setup correctly and was blocking connections.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more about your solution? I have a website with sse connection that jams the website over night. it's not a memory leak issue for sure, it's something in the networking but i don't know what